# Change wrong behaviour of screenshot Shift-Command-4

Tags: keyboard, screen-capture

Since today Shift-Command-4 gives me the camera symbol, meaning that it will screenshot the active window. Pressing the spacebar then, changes to the selection tool.
Usually the behaviour is the other way around: selection-tool, when pressing space the camera appears.

How do I get back the default behaviour? I already restored defaults in System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcut. Didn't help.

Comment: While you shouldn't have to reboot after restoring the defaults, nonetheless I'd reboot and see if you still have the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it unfortunately didn't help